# How to add hours?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

How to add below two drop-down hours as follows below:-

In my app I have a drop-down box of strings that shows possible hours in 12-hour time for the user to select

```
9am
9.30am
10am
10.30am
11am
11.30am
12pm
12.30pm
etc,
```

And another drop-down box of strings that shows possible hours like

```
1hour
2hour
3hour
etc
```

When user select first drop-down after that he/she select second drop-down then i want to add these values and select difference of hours like

if user select

first value=11.30pm

second value=2hours

then ,i want to show End Time=1.30AM

Comment: is this question belongs to SQL server 2008?? why tag is added??

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx

Comment: will the operation be performed on database side or .net side?

Comment: i want it on in my c# code..

Comment: A tip: don't just use plain strings to fill your dropdown, use [ListItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.aspx)s. The `.Text` is the displayed value, the `.Value` is for internal use where you can make sure it's easy to parse into a `TimeSpan` or number of hours (or maybe minutes).

Answer (score 4):

You can use a combination of `DateTime.ParseExact`, `int.Parse`, `DateTime.AddHours` and `DateTime.ToString`:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("11.30am", "hh.mmtt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); 
var digits = "2hours".TakeWhile(Char.IsDigit);  // take only the first digit(s)
int hours = int.Parse(new string(digits.ToArray()));
String result = dt.AddHours(hours).ToString("h.mmtt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Result: `1.30PM` (so your desired result is incorrect because it's PM instead of AM)

---

In your case you have to handle the `DropDownList`'s `SelectedIndexChanged`-events and use the `SelectedValue` property. But you should use more maningful values in the `ListItem`s anyway.

For example:

```
<asp:DropDownList id="DdlTime" runat="server"
     OnSelectedIndexChanged="OnSelectedIndexChangedMethod">

   <asp:ListItem value="690">
      11.30am
   </asp:ListItem>
   etc.... 
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Here you can use `TimeSpan.FromMinutes(int.Parse(ddlTime.SelectedValue))` to get the `TimeSpan` or directly `DateTime.Today.AddMinutes(int.Parse(ddlTime.SelectedValue))`.

Comment: how solve this in drop-down i have a value in 10am,10.30am etc,in one drop-down and in other as 1hrs,2hrs and client want the difference

Comment: @PraveenSingh: you have to handle the `DropDownList`'s `SelectedIndexChanged`-events and use the `SelectedValue` property. Note that i've edited my answer accordingly.